# Loading image from a remote server in pyglet or PIL / python

Tags: python, user-interface, python-imaging-library, pyglet

I would like to feed images from a remote machine into pyglet (though I am open to other platforms where I can present images and record user's mouse clicks and keystrokes). Currently I am trying to do it using `flask` on the remote server and pulling it down with `requests`

```
import requests

from PIL import Image
import io
import pyglet
import numpy as np

r = requests.get('http://{}:5000/test/cat2.jpeg'.format(myip),)
```

#### This does not work:

```
im = pyglet.image.load(io.StringIO(r.text))

# Error: 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 178, in load
    file = open(filename, 'rb')

TypeError: invalid file: <_io.StringIO object at 0x7f6eb572bd38>
```

#### This also does not work:

```
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.text.encode()))

# Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-68-409ca9b8f6f6>", line 1, in <module>
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.text.encode()))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2274, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))

OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f6eb5a8b6a8>
```

Is there another way to do it without saving files on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example isn't working properly because I'm having encoding issues. But this will get you on the way of using manual `ImageData` objects to manipulate images:

```
import pyglet, urllib.request

# == The Web part:
img_url = 'http://hvornum.se/linux.jpg'
web_response = urllib.request.urlopen(img_url)
img_data = web_response.read()

# == Loading the image part:
window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=False, width=700, height=921)
image = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.ImageData(700, 921, 'RGB', img_data))

# == Stuff to render the image:
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    image.draw()
    window.flip()

@window.event
def on_close():
    print("I'm closing now")

pyglet.app.run()
```

Now to the more convenient, less manual way of doing things would be to use the `io.BytesIO` dummy file-handle and toss that into `pyglet.image.load()` with the parameter `file=dummyFile` like so:

```
import pyglet, urllib.request
from io import BytesIO

# == The Web part:
img_url = 'http://hvornum.se/linux.jpg'
web_response = urllib.request.urlopen(img_url)
img_data = web_response.read()
dummy_file = BytesIO(img_data)

# == Loading the image part:
window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=False, width=700, height=921)
image = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('noname.jpg', file=dummy_file))

# == Stuff to render the image:
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    image.draw()
    window.flip()

@window.event
def on_close():
    print("I'm closing now")

pyglet.app.run()
```

Works on my end and is rather quick as well.
One last note, try putting images into `pyglet.sprite.Sprite` objects, they tend to be quicker, easier to work with and gives you a whole bunch of nifty functions to work with (such as easy positioning, `spr.scale` and rotate functions)

Comment: I do use Sprite downstream. The syntax with `file=` looks quite confusing... What is the difference between the `BytesIO` fileobject way and the first way you show?

Comment: @DimaLituiev The second option will down the line create a `ImageData` object. So the main difference is that the first option will short-cut a lot of the work and create a `ImageData` object straight away. The down side to that is that you need to figure out the image format, the image width/height and insert the data in a correct way manually. It gives you greater creative freedom over the data and the creation - but it will require more logic and work.
Hence my second alternative which purely rely on the built in mechanics of Python or in this case - Pyglet :)

Answer (score 0):

You can show a remote image by PIL as follows:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO

r = requests.get('http://{}:5000/test/cat2.jpeg', stream=True)
sio = StringIO(r.raw.read())
im = Image.open(sio)
im.show()
```

Note that the `stream=True` option is necessary to create a `StringIO` object from the data.  Also, not using `io.StringIO` but `StringIO.StringIO`.