# Load images from data stream and not from a file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-3.7, pyglet, bytesio

I have a program (in Pyglet) in which I would like to keep the icons of them in the form of bytes, then convert them into temporary images and pass them to the program to be able to use them.

This is a dictionary where the data of the two icons are present:

```
ico = {
    "ico_16": {
        "dimension": (16, 16),
        "byte": b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x10\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\x1f\xf3\xffa\x00\x00\x00\x04gAMA\x00\x00\xb1\x8f\x0b\xfca\x05\x00\x00\x00 cHRM\x00\x00z&\x00\x00\x80\x84\x00\x00\xfa\x00\x00\x00\x80\xe8\x00\x00u0\x00\x00\xea`\x00\x00:\x98\x00\x00\x17p\x9c\xbaQ<\x00\x00\x00\x06bKGD\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\xa0\xbd\xa7\x93\x00\x00\x00\x07tIME\x07\xe2\x08\x05\x12-\x0f?\xc1\x9b\xba\x00\x00\x03\x0fIDAT8\xcbU\x92Kh\\U\x00\x86\xbfs\xee\x99{g\xe6>f:\xe9<,3i51\xa6\x92B\xb5iHQ\n%.\n\xf6A)E(\xb5YtS\x8a R\\\xe8F\r\xe2^\x10WZ\x91\xae\x8a\x8b`\t\xbaP\xac\x0b\xad\x8a\xf4\x85\n\xadv\xa16\x19\'N\x9b\xcc+3\xb9\xcf\xe3b\xda\x85\xff\xf2\x87\xff\xdb\xfc\x9f`Q\xc31\x01\x07\xce\xc0\xee\xb9\x14?^~\x81^{\x9e`\xf3y\x92\xa4\x0c\x80\x94\xab\x98\xe9\xefpr\x9f2{\xe4kn~\x13r\xe5#X\xd4\x18L\x1f\x85\x9b\xdf\xc2\xe8\xce\n\xb7\xae\xbcK\xeb\xfe\x02A0\x8dP\x1e\x86)\x91J\x92h\x0f\x7f0E\xbf\xf3"\xcb\xb7+\x14*7\xe8\xb4{L\xeeC\x10h\x83\xb3\x1fV\xf9y\xe9\x036\xba\x87\xb0l\xc8\xb8`f\xc0H\x81\x90\x10\x87\x10\x0c\xa0\xdf\x01\xbf\x07\xb6\xbb\xc4\xdeC\xaf\xf0\xf1\xb9e\x83\xf1\xd7J\xf2\xea\xe2\x82\x8a\xa2\x97\x12\xd3\x037\x0fv\x0e\xbc"\xaa2\x0e\xb9\x1a\xda\x19\x01C\x82J\x81\xca\x92\xb22\x13\x84\xbe\xa7\x93}W\r\xd2\xe5\xe3\x8f\xef\xa8\xbe\xbe\xe7\xf8i\xab\xbe\x16\x10\xa1!\xe3\xa2JO\xb2\xff\xf0Q2\xa3\xbb\x99|z\x92\xd6\x86\x8f\xef\x87\xd8\xd5\xa78p\xfa\x0c~\xaf;\xde\xbe\xf5\xd3\x1dE\xfd\xce\x89\xcc\x13s\xae\xceo\xc7\xac\xcd\x90x\x7f#S\x06\xc2\xdeA*_\xc6\xf1$\xdb=\xe8\x0ff\xb8\xd6IHo{\x0c\x9d\xabaes.\xf5\x1b\'\x14\xfd\xf5imXh\x99\x86\xc2.\x9eyv\n\xcb\x92\\\xfb]\x90\x08\x89Pp\xbb\x03\xa9b\x8dL\xb5\x8bN\xbbh\x91F\x1bi\xe8\xb7\xf6*\xe2\xb0(\x0c\x05\x02\x84\x9dEf!2@:\x80\x04\x12\x88|h>P\xd4\xc6\xc6h\xb6\x14\x18\x02\x0c\x05IX\x94<\x8a\x00\x14h\xf9p\xa8\x1e\xf6\t\x88X\xd3\xb8\xf7\x00;k\xe0\x8cd\xd0\x02\x10b\xa8\x08\x86\xd9\xd4q\x08\x1a\x84\x1er\x1e\xf1\x10C\x00qH\xd4\xfe\x93\xc6\xf2\n\xd5\x92F\x03\xc41H\xb3)q\xb6^\x17I@\xab\xd1d\xe7\xd6\x01A\xbbM{u\x9d\xa9r\xc8z+\x81\x10d\x1c"7W\xf8\xe7\x8f_\x18\x89\xd6(Y@\x12\x83W\xba\xae\xe4\xcc\xc1\xcf\xad\x82\xbd\xff\xeeW\x9f9!\x12_\x18$R\x91\xcdo!\xb6\xca\xcc\xceN\x12\xf7\xd7\x88\xda\xf7\xa0\xdb\xe2\xb7\xef\rF\'\xc6P[\n=1}\xf0\xb2P_\xeaQyaa!\xf8\xf5\x87y,\x17\x9c\x1cX\x19H\xa5\xc1r1\xbd\x02\x89? Z\xaf\xc3\xa0\x0bA\x88\x88\x03\xd4\xd8\xae\x8b\xf1\xfc\x1bo\xa9\xa8B\x03\xa7\xf06J\x14\xe8\xd4\x0f\xe3w\x86*\xa7,P&\xc1\xfd\xbf \x89\xfe\xa7\xb2v\xf2K\xe1\xc8\xb6w(Q\x17\\X\x85W\xf7\xc0s\xc7*\xd4\xef\xbe\xc9F\xf7e4y\x0csx\x15@\x1cA\x1c\x80\xa0\x85\xed^\xa4:\xf1\x1e_\xbc\xdf\xe0\x93\x7f\x91\xe4K\xd0]\x86\xcd\x8d\x06s\xa7\xceS\xaa\x9e\xc4v/!\xf5\n\xb1\x1f\x11\xfb\x11R\xaf`\xbb\x97(UO2w\xea<\x9b\xfd\x06ZC\xae\xc8\x7f\xde\x160\x90\xb5\xbaI\xa8\x00\x00\x00%tEXtdate:create\x002018-08-05T18:45:15+00:00\xbf\xac\x1c\xb8\x00\x00\x00%tEXtdate:modify\x002018-08-05T18:45:15+00:00\xce\xf1\xa4\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
    },
    "ico_32": {
        "dimension": (32, 32),
        "byte": b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x08\x06\x00\x00\x00szz\xf4\x00\x00\x00\x04gAMA\x00\x00\xb1\x8f\x0b\xfca\x05\x00\x00\x00 cHRM\x00\x00z&\x00\x00\x80\x84\x00\x00\xfa\x00\x00\x00\x80\xe8\x00\x00u0\x00\x00\xea`\x00\x00:\x98\x00\x00\x17p\x9c\xbaQ<\x00\x00\x00\x06bKGD\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\xa0\xbd\xa7\x93\x00\x00\x00\x07tIME\x07\xe2\x08\x05\x12+\x1a\x04F\xd8\xd7\x00\x00\x08\xc3IDATX\xc3\x9d\x97il\\\xd5\x15\xc7\x7f\xf7\xad\xb3\xd8c{<\xb6gL\xec\xd8\xb1]\xc7\xc4\x91\x1bB\x0c\x844II\xa9h\x8b(\x82\xb2\xb4H]>\xb0tQEAU@\xb4\xaa\xdb\xaa-\x15-\x82~@\x84(m?P\xf5C\x05\xdd\xa8\x8ah\xd9B\x81`\'\r\x11 \x12;\xc4\x89q\xf06\xf6,\x9ey\xb3\xbc\xad\x1f\xee\x9b\xd8NhUq\xa5\xa3;\xbao\xee9\xffs\xee\xb9\xe7\xfc\xaf\xe0\xc3\xc6]O@n\x01BQ\x98\x9d\x84\x07\x1fQ\xf8\xf1\x0f\xfa\xc9/\xee\xa1\xb4\xfcI*\xd6f\xecj\x12\xcf\x8d\x02\xa0\xa8Etc\x163\xf2\x16\xe1\xfa\x17\x895?\xcf\xf7\x7fx\x82\xfb\xee\xf6HvC\xb9\x08\r-\xf0\xf8\x1d\x17\x98\x12\x00<\xed\xaf\xac\xfc\xf9a8\xfd6\xc4S\xf0\x8b\x9f\x08\xbe\xb3w\x98\xcc\xecW\xc9/^C1\xdfA\xb5\xac\xe2\xb9\xe0\xafl\x07_\xfeTT0B.\xd1\xd8\xfb\xc4\x9a\x9f\xa5)\xf9[\x1e\xfe\xf9(\xdf}\xc0gi\x06\xba\x06\xe1\xf3\xf7\xac\xd8\xbaA \xd6\x18\x0f\x033s\xf0\xfb\x11H\xacK1s\xean\x16\xcf~\x8d\xfcR\x0b\x8e\x03\x8a\x06\xaa.gEY\x0b\xc0\xf3\xc0s\xc0\xb5\xe5\xaci\x10\x8b\xa7i\xbe\xe8\xd7\xa46<Bzz\x86/\x8e@\xaa\rJ\xab#p\x0e\x80/\x88\x08\xb8F\xf8\\\x7f\xff6fN\xfe\x92\x85\xe9OP)\x83f\x80\x16\x02M\x07E\x97\x9e~(\x00W\x1aw\xaa\xe0T\xa4\x98!hY\xf7/R\xbd\xf7\xf0\xa7\x9f\x8d\xf1\xac/\xb0|@\xf8\x00*\xb7\x8c\x08@\x05\xa1p-\n\xef\x88=\x9cy\xfb\x00sS[p=0\xeb\xc0\x8c\x82\x19\x01#\x0cF\x08\xcc0\xe8!0L9\xebf\x00\xd2\x005\x88\x92\xaaI\xa0v\x05\n\xd9N\x9c\xean\xae\xbc\xf58\xf7\xef>\xc3qq\x0e\xbd\xca-#\x1a\xbe\xaf\xd3)4F\xf6og\xfc\x8d},L\xf5\xa2\xe8\x10\xaa\x97\x89hD\x02\xc3\xa1\x15\x10F8X\x0f\xc0\xe8\x86\x8c\x90\xaa\xcb\xf0+jpT\x9a\x8c\x8c\x95k\xc6u\xb63\x96=\xc6U[g\xc9\xf9\nB\xa0r\xcb\x88IT\x98\xbc:\xd6\xcb\xd8\xdf\x1e\xe5\x83\x93\x9bQL\x087\x04\xdeG\xa4\xa7Fh\xc5{#\x1aD\xa5\x1e\x8c:\tD\x0f\x05\x9e\xabR\x94@\xd4\xe0\xd8<\x0f\x8a\xd98\xae;\x80h}\x8d\xaeu\xcb\xd8\xf8\x1a\x02\x83\n1\x8e\xbe\xf0\rr\xe9aR\x1b\xc1\x13\xe0:\xa0\xa9\xa0)\xa0*R\xa9f\x80\x16\x06=\x02\xe18\xd4\'\xc0\x15\xc8<\x11`[\xb0<\x07\xd5\x02he\xd0L\xd0\x1d)\r\xed \x1c\xc8.\x0cs\xf4\x85o\xb2i\xf8G\x08\xf2*w\x8e\xd4\xf3\xf2s;\x18\x1f\xdb\xdb\xbb\xfb\xd3\xe1\x9bn\xbf\x03\xadc#gg\xb32\xbf\x0c]\x86V\x0b\xce\xdb\xac\x87\xba6\xba\x87\xaf\xe4\xa6\xcf\\F\xa8\xad\x93\xf7\x97\xe3t\x0en\xa4\xf3c\xeb\x99\x9f\xcb\xcaDTT\xe9\xb9\x1aB$\xba\xd8\xf5\xa5\xdb\xb8\xe6\x86\xebIW\x15r\x13\xefl\x00\xed\xdf\x0c\xf6N)\x14\x882~\xf8\x0bxn\xd3\xce\xdd\xbb\x98v\xa2\x0c\r\r\x10\xe9\xda\x0c\xd1\x16\x087\xc9\\\xa8\x85\xdcl\x84\xc6\x0evm\xe9\xe1\xac\x1b\xe5\xd2\xdef"\x9d}\xacO\xa5\xb8{\xe7z\xa2]\x9b \x9c\x80P\x83<\xc6H3\xb1\x9eA.\x1d\xeag\xda\x8d\xb2m\xe7N\xb0+ML\x1c\xb9\x89e\xa2\nG^\xe9c~r\x07\xa8(\x9a\xc1\xf8\x07\x16%\x1b\xb4\xfa$D\xdb\x03eq0\x9b \xd4\x0c\xe1\x16\x88\xa4\xd0T\x83\x89\x0cT=0\x1a\x15\x1c]\xb0)\xaer\xd9P\x0f\xc4:\xe4\x9eP\x13D\x12\xe8u\t\x8a\x15\x9f\xe3\xd3E\x14=\x04B\x83\xf9\xc9\x1d\x1c~\xb9Oc\xf2\xd8v\x96\xd3I\x12\xbd\xf8BEQM\x84\xd0!\x94\x84\xba\x12(\x05"\xcd\x11tC#\xb7X\x02\xaf\x0e\xcc\x14\xbe\xa2!T\x10\x02\x08\x81\xad\xc1\x81S\xd0\xdb\xd1\xc8hG7\x85I\x1b\xec"`\xe2\x1b1\x84PQ\xb40\x08\x0b\xf40d\xcf$\x99<v\xa5\xc6\xd2\xf4\xe5TK*z\x18\x84\x02\xaa)g\xb3\x15\xa2\x1a\xb1\xa4\xc7\x97\xafj!l\xaa<5\x96\xe1\xd4\xb8\x07f<(\xbd\xf26\x0bMV\x92\x93Y\xd0\x84\xc2%\x17\xb7sp!\x0fVF\xa2\xd3cR\xa7b\x82(\xcb$\xae\x96T\x96\xce^\xa1P\xcc\xf4\xe3{2\xc3\x85\xe0\x9c[\x86\x01\xe1VR\xedI,_\xe7\xd0\xac\xc2\x86T\\\x1e\x89\xae\xae\xee$\xe7\x86\xe2\xc2\x1b\x93\xd0\x9b\x8aR\x97J\x81\xd9,E\xab\x0f\x00hr\xd6\x0c\xf0=\xb02\xfd\nU\xab-\xe8h\x81\xd2@\xab\x06\x84\x14\x84\xaePq\xc0\xb2\x01U\x80)\xe4\xb7\xd5\xc6]\xc0\x93K\xf94Le\x14\xb6\xf4\x07\xf9b\xb4\x80\x16\tt+R\x7f\xcdV\xd5jS\xf0\x9c0\x8a\x90\xb5]\x08\xa9\xa5\x16^mU\x98k\xc5\xb3\xb6\xb6zx\x81\xf8@\xd9\xe7\xc8\x84M_\xd2\xa4\xae-\x01F\x93\x8c\x98X\x05\xbaf\xcbs\xc2\xe7\xabZ\x15Oy\xae5\x00k\x80}\x18\x00?\x98\xed\n\x99\x99,S\x8b6[\xfa"\x10\xd2\x11\xea\x9a\xe6\x7f\x9e\x19E+\xe1\x05\xdd\xcc\xf7\xd7~=\x7f\xc3j\x00\xab=\xaaE\xc0\xf3\xc1\xceA)\xcd\x91\x139\xfaZ}\xa2\t\xf0\x95\xf3ty\xbe\xb4\xa5h%\x05#2/\x17\x9ds\x9du\x8d\xfc?\xa3\x16\x01\xdf\x01\'\x0b\xf6\x12\x99\x0f\xe6\x99J\x97\xd9\xd2\x05\x9e\xbaJ\x97\x8flN\x00FdN\xa1.~\x02\xa1\x80c\x83\xef\xe1{\xdeJbUV\x94\xfb5#\x8e\xfc&\x08\xd6\xd6\x80v\xc0\xc9\xcb(\x14\x178\xfcn\x9a\x9e\xb8O\xac>\xb0_\x03\xe1\xba\xf2\xeeF\x9bO($\xd6\x8fbD\\\xec\x12\xf8\x1ev\xa1\x80U\xb2\x19h\x87h#\x0c\xb6\xc2|\xceg~\xd1\xa3\xb3\x01\xe2M\xd0\x11\x97y\x95-\x04\xb4\xc2\xa9\x01u\xc0Y\x96 \xcai\xb2g\xa685[\xe0\xf2\x0e\xd9\xab\xe4\x7f<\xb0\xcb`F\\\x12\x9d\xa3\x1a=\x97\x1c\xe2\xe4\x9bs\xd8V;x\xf8\xd9\x19^|\xd5\xe3s\xbb\xba\xd8\xb6Ng!_\xe6\xb5#\x0bXE\x97\x93u\tn\x1d\xaa\xc7\xf5\xe1\x95q\x9flZE\xf4\x08\xbc\x8a\xb4\x8df\x83\xbd\x0c\x95\xbc<c\xc7\xe1\xe8\xb1\x06n\x1b\xbc\x18\xdf\x15\xfc\xdd\xb6\xf1=\x07\xec\x12\xc4\xda\xe6\xe8\xdd\xfa\x86\xc6\xa6\xe1I\xde\x1d}\xbd\xb1\xce\xb8\xb1\xa9>\x82\x9d9\xca\xe2\xb1\t~w&\x89\xd9\x10\xa5T,\xe1\x97\xcb \x04\x07\x9f\x8b0\xda\xd4\x88\'L\xaa\x96\x89\xda\xd4\x86\xe2\'\xe9N\xf8t4\t2\x8be\xa8\xe4\xa0\xba\x1c\xe4\x94E\xe1$<\xf7v3\x9f\xda\xd8B\xb5\xb8@cW=u\x03\x9b)\x94\xbdC\x0c\x0eOj\x18Xl\xbd\xfa\xaf=\xc9\xd0\xd5o\xbd;\x11\x9b}\xf3 d\xb2\xb8\xd6\x14\x96a\x80\xaeI\x86\xa3\xaaPT)/\xe9\x01?\xac\xc3\xad\xcc\xf2\xca;6W\xf4\'\xc8Y6/\xbd5\x0eVZ\x02pl\x19\xf2b\x9e\x7f\xbc`\xb2`}\x9c\xb9#\xafs\\\xdd\xc8E\xdb\xf7\xe4Od\xbcg\xd0\xb1\x04O\xfbI4\x1a\xc4\xf3\x7f\xb8\xdf?\xf4\x97\xaf\xb04+\xdbn(\x1ap\xbe\x80\xeb\xd5@(\x01\xedRMINB1D$\x8a_-C~\x01\xcaYIL\x9c*8.8\x9e\xac^\x9a\x0e\x8bS\x10\xad\x87\xcb\xaf{\x92=7<\x88\xc3\xa2\x06\x94Qq\xfd\xd6\xf5\xbf"\x14\x1e\xc0)\x0e\xe3\x96\xc1-\x81\x1d\x96 43\xe0{j@:\xb5\x80\x1d\xeb`\xa5\xf1\x17\x05\xf8\xae\xa4\xe4NY\x12Q\xa7\nvM*P.\xc8\xeb\xd3v\xd1a:\xfa\x1fCa\x11(k@\x85\n\x0e\xbb\x87\'\x98<z\x1fV\xe6\t\xe6N\xf7\xe2:\xe0V\xc1\tI&\xa4\x05\xccHY\xc5\xf9\x84\xbaR\xa3k\xef\x02\xa7*\xf7\xd5\x0c\xdbe\xa8X2K\x93\x1b\xdec\xe0\xb2\x07\xd8\xba\xe98\x19\\d\x17\xa7\n(\xcc!\xd8\x7f\xe7An\x9c\xfe:\x9e\xfd\x18\x0b\xd3}\x94\xf2\xd2+\xd7\x96Q\xa8\x91\xce\x1a\xe1\x14A9\xf4\x83\xca\xe6\xd5\xa2`\xcb7\x81]\x86jI\xde\xd5\xd6\x8e\t\xd6o\xfa\x16\xf7\xde\xf6\x12G\xa9]JO\xf0\xb4\xbfR$#\xc0g\xa3>\xd7}{\x1b3\xef=\xcc\xc2\xf4\x0eI8W\x1d\xc3G}\x98\xb4\xf7\xdd\xcb\x1f\x7f:\xca3\xbe\xa0z\xce\xa2\xaf\\P|\xf7\x9d\x80Bv\x8c\xee\xa1\x9b\xe9\x1cx\x88xk\x1a\\(\xe7\xc1\xcaA)\x07\xa5\xfc\x7f\x91\x1cXY\xf9_\\\x88\xb7\xa6\xe9\x1cx\x88\xee\xa1\x9b),\x8d\xf2\x9b9\x10k\x0b\xfd\xda\xbef\x01\xaf=U;\xb7\x19\xf6\x1f\xd8K\xf7\xd0\xb5t\x0e\xec#\xd1~\x1a3\xe4\xe2\xd9\x92v\x9fo\xbcZ\x00\xcf\x063\xe4\x92h?M\xe7\xc0>\xba\x87\xae\xe5\x89\x03{\xa9X3TJ\xf0\xe4\xf7dy\xff\x1f\xfdN\x8e\xbb\xf6Cn\xfe\xa3>\xcf_"\xd6\xfc\xcf\x0b\x9f\xe7\xad\xf0\xf8\xed\x17\x98\xfa\x0f\x10\x99\xc4\xde3\xad\xf4\x83\x00\x00\x00%tEXtdate:create\x002018-08-05T18:43:26+00:00\r\xd5q\x81\x00\x00\x00%tEXtdate:modify\x002018-08-05T18:43:26+00:00|\x88\xc9=\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
    }
}
```

While this is the part of the script in which it is converted into temporary images and passed to Pyglet:

```
temp_ico = []

for ic, ic_key in ico.items():
    with BytesIO() as ic_key["byte"]:
        from PIL import Image
        with Image.new("RGB", ic_key["dimension"]) as ico_img:
            ico_img.save(ic_key["byte"], format="PNG")
            ico_img = pyglet.image.load(ico_img)
            temp_ico.append(ico_img)
self.set_icon(temp_ico[0], temp_ico[1])
```

The problem I'm having is that Pyglet, with: `pyglet.image.load()`, expects the file path and not the file itself.
Since the file is not physical, I do not know how to get the path of it to get it used by Pyglet. Do you have any suggestions or advice on how to solve the problem?

Edit:
I tried with both answers obtained from "Torxed":

```
temp_ico = []
self.temp_sp = []

for ic, ic_key in ico.items():
    ico_img = pyglet.image.ImageData(ic_key["dimension"][0], ic_key["dimension"][1], 'RGB', ic_key["byte"])
    temp_ico.append(ico_img)
    temp = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ico_img)
    temp.x = randint(0, 100)
    temp.y = randint(0, 100)
    self.temp_sp.append(temp)

self.set_icon(temp_ico[0], temp_ico[1])
```

And:

```
temp_ico = []
self.temp_sp = []

for ic, ic_key in ico.items():
    ico_img = pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern((255, 255, 255, 255)).create_image(ic_key["dimension"][0], ic_key["dimension"][1])
    ico_img.set_data('RGB', ico_img.width * len('RGB'), ic_key["byte"])
    temp_ico.append(ico_img)
    temp = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ico_img)
    temp.x = randint(0, 100)
    temp.y = randint(0, 100)
    self.temp_sp.append(temp)

self.set_icon(temp_ico[0], temp_ico[1])
```

But in both methods I get a mix of confusing pixels and not the original image.
I have also modified the method in which I obtained the printing of the image bytes. Before I used this method:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
with BytesIO() as output:
    from PIL import Image
    with Image.open("ico_32.png") as img:
        img.convert('RGB').save(output, "png")
    data = output.getvalue()
    print(data)
```

Which I had obtained from here [Answer by: perillaseed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351254/python-script-to-convert-image-into-byte-array)
But then I changed to:

```
s = open("ico_32.png", "rb")
data = s.read()
print(data)
s.close()
f = open('new_image.png', 'wb')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

If I go to check the new saved image, it is exactly the same as the original, so I copy the byte string manually, insert it in the dictionary and it does not work.
Here are the visual results:
[image: Print Bytes Image]
[image: First Test]
[image: Second Test]

Also, I wanted to warn that I put the two icons as sprite and designed to see them better, since they were too small on the actual icon of the program.

To respond to snakecharmerb, I tried when you answered the suggestion you gave me, but as he also answered Torxed, I get the error he reported himself.

Edit2:

[image]
[image]

I tried to change the icons (since the two I used were only for testing and not the final ones of the program) with two others, but I get the same result. Above are the original ones, under the new ones.

[image]
[image]

Bytes string (new_ico_16):

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x10\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00(-\x0fS\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x01\xc1\x00\x00\x01\xc1\x01E\x85\\9\x00\x00\x00\x19tEXtSoftware\x00www.inkscape.org\x9b\xee<\x1a\x00\x00\x00\xd2PLTE\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00O33gNNm/1l/1t./\x87`cy*-\x86_b\x8f*+\x8efiz,/\x90hl\x94!$\xa1\'(\xa3{|\x8eln\xb4$&\xb9 !\xa1\x88\x8b\x8b"#\xae\x8f\x91\xbc\xa8\xaa\xbe\xb0\xb2\xe4\x19\x1a\xec\x1d\x1d\x90\x8d\x90\x85\x88\x8c\x89\x8b\x8e\x8b\x92\x96\x90\x95\x98\x96\x9e\xa2\x97\x9f\xa3\xa2or\xa4`b\xa9\x19\x1a\xaa\x1b\x1d\xaa\xb5\xba\xaa\xb6\xbb\xab\xb2\xb7\xab\xb3\xb8\xab\xb4\xb8\xab\xba\xc0\xb7\x11\x12\xb9\xc4\xc9\xbe\xc0\xc2\xbf\xbb\xbc\xc4\x14\x15\xd0\xde\xe3\xd6\t\t\xd8\n\n\xd8\xe5\xea\xda\n\n\xda\x0b\x0b\xda\xe6\xeb\xdb\xe7\xec\xdc\xe8\xec\xe0\r\r\xe1\r\r\xe2\xec\xef\xe2\xec\xf0\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\x10\x10\xe8\xf0\xf3\xec\xea\xeb\xf4\x16\x16\xf5\xf8\xfa\xff\x1a\x1a\xff\xff\xff\xeb\x12-N\x00\x00\x00\x1ctRNS\x00\x01-4\x81\x82\x91\x9d\x9e\x9e\xb0\xb2\xb8\xc1\xd0\xd1\xd8\xd9\xe5\xe9\xf1\xf2\xf2\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfd\xfe(\xffw\x99\x00\x00\x00\xb0IDAT\x18\x19=\xc1\x89\x1a\x81@\x14\x06\xd0\x7f\n\x955Id\xdf\xf7\xc24\xd6\x90\xf5\xfd_\xc9\x1d\xfa:\x07\x92\x92\xc9\x96J\xd9\x8c\x82?\x96\xb6\xde?V\x9a\x81\xb0|\xe3\x19\x85\xfb}\x18=\x1by\x06 \xe5\x9ey\xec\xec\xa6\x00\xa5\x12\xf0DPQ\xa0\xef\xb8\xb4\xd9pi\xa7\xa3\xc8\xa5\xc1l6\xe4R\x11\xd5\x15\x19\xcf\xbb\x9d\xf5hE\xaahzd\xbah\xb7\xfc\x89G\x9a\xb0\x85\xd4\xf7\xfd\x9e\x90l\x14\x8e\x82l\x97\xcb\xad \xc7\x02\xd4\xfaA$\x0eu\x15\xd0n\x17\x11\xbb\xdc4\x00\xac\xfcx\xdd\xaf\xa7\xd3\xf5\xfez\x94\x19\x083j\x9f\x9f\x9a\xc1\xf0\xa7\xe6L\xc71s*\xc8\x17B\xf5#3;\xd8r\xdc\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
```

Bytes string (new_ico_32):

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x08\x03\x00\x00\x00D\xa4\x8a\xc6\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x03\x82\x00\x00\x03\x82\x01\x83\x06\xfdz\x00\x00\x00\x19tEXtSoftware\x00www.inkscape.org\x9b\xee<\x1a\x00\x00\x01\xb3PLTE\xff\xff\xff+++$$I77739944;77;F47UFIJ36K27M27ZIL[JM[JNG37J37SGKN26L26J36N14T15UIMU25P16U15O26Q/2YLPWLOUJNYMQ\x8f)+^RUXORYOS^SV_TWK15\xaa&\'\xae%\'\x89%\'YRV\xc9\x1f \xd5 !\xd7\x1f NMQ\x95\x8c\x8e\xad\xa8\xa9\xb2\xac\xae\xc5"#V\\`Z_d^?B_KOj8;kptnDGnruotxpy~qtxtvy\x81\x88\x8c\x82\x89\x8d\x82\x90\x96\x83?A\x8a\x91\x95\x8a\x92\x96\x8c\x8b\x8e\x8d\x90\x93\x91\x92\x94\x93\x96\x98\x95\x8f\x91\x99\x1a\x1b\x9a\xa3\xa8\x9c\xa7\xac\x9d\xa9\xad\xa2\x18\x19\xa3\x18\x1a\xa8\xb7\xbd\xb1\xc3\xc9\xb2\xbd\xc2\xb4\xbf\xc3\xb6\xc1\xc6\xb8\x14\x15\xb8\xc3\xc8\xba\xc3\xc8\xbb\xcc\xd2\xc1\x0f\x0f\xc5\xc5\xc6\xc7\xd6\xdc\xc8\xce\xd0\xc9\xca\xcb\xce\x0b\x0b\xd0\xd0\xd1\xd0\xdd\xe2\xd4\n\n\xd4\xe1\xe6\xd5\t\t\xd5 !\xd5\xd4\xd4\xd5\xd5\xd6\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd5\xe2\xe7\xd6\t\t\xd7\xd6\xd7\xd7\xd8\xd8\xd8\xe5\xea\xd9\n\n\xda\x0b\x0b\xdb\xe7\xec\xdc\xe8\xec\xde\x0c\x0c\xdf\r\r\xdf\xea\xee\xe0\r\r\xe1\r\r\xe1\xeb\xef\xe2\xec\xef\xe2\xec\xf0\xe7\x10\x10\xe8\xf0\xf3\xe9\x1d\x1d\xe9\xea\xea\xeb\xf2\xf4\xed\x13\x13\xee\xf4\xf6\xf3\x15\x15\xf3\xf7\xf9\xf4\x15\x15\xf4\x16\x16\xf4\xf8\xf9\xf5\xf8\xf9\xf6\x17\x17\xf6\xf9\xf9\xfa\x18\x18\xfa\xfc\xfc\xfc\x1a\x1b\xfc\xfc\xfc\xfe\x1a\x1a\xfe\xfe\xfe\xff\x1a\x1a\xff\xff\xff0\xafA\xf0\x00\x00\x004tRNS\x00\x06\x07\x17-JJ\x8a\x96\xa9\xad\xad\xb9\xbe\xbe\xd0\xd7\xde\xdf\xe0\xe2\xe2\xe4\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe8\xe9\xee\xee\xef\xf0\xf2\xf2\xf4\xf6\xf6\xf6\xf6\xf7\xf7\xf7\xf8\xfa\xfd\xfd\xfd\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xce2\x02\x1d\x00\x00\x01\xe4IDAT\x18\x19u\xc1\x07[RQ\x18\x00\xe0\xef\xde\xc3T\x14q\xef\xbd\xf7\xa0\xc8\xcar\x90JZ\xa2\xe2^X\xa8p\xec\x88\x88\x8a{/p\x9c\xef\'\x87>r\xb8(\xbc/D\xc9\xea\xa4\xb4\xf4\xec\xec\xf4\xb4$\xb5\x0c\xef\x11}^\xd9\xca=\x0f\xbb_)\xcb\xd3\x13\x88%is;\xb8BG\xaeV\x02\x05b\xac{\xe41\x1e\xeb\x8c\x04\x04UF3\xe7<xyz\xb0\xeb\xf5\xee\x1e\x9c^\x069\xe7\xcd\x19*xE2\x8f8?\xdf\xa2\n[\xe7\x9c\x1fe\x12x!\x19\x9b\xf8\x95\x9f\xbe\xe1\xbf\xe2MF\t\x9eik\x83;4\x8e\x9d`\xad\x16\xc2H\xfe\xad\x97\xc6\xe5\xbd\xcd\'\x00\xa0o\xdc\xa0\tl4\xea\x01\xe4\x02?M\xc8_ \x83\xba\x9eF\xb9\xec}}v\x17\x8d\xaaWC\xf2$\x15f-V\x87\xc3j\x99\xa5\xc2d2d-\xd1\x08\x97e\x8a\x8d\x8f\xb3\x85\x8f\x7fh\xc4R\x16\x14R\xc1ne\x9d\xdd\xdd_\xf0\xe7\x08\x15\n\xa1fH\xf8\xec\x98\x188a=n\xe7\xa7!\xa1\x06Z\x86\x85\xaf\x8e\x89\x01<\xe9q;;\x87\x85\x16h`\xc2\xef\x1f\xec\xdb\xe0\xe0w\xb4\xfdbB\x03\x94.\xb3\x08\xcf\x87\x05t\xbb\xf1\x9f\xf9/\x8bX.\x85\xd4i&\x8c\x9amN\xa7\xcd<\xca\x84\xe9T\xd0\xf43\xc13\xd6\xdb\xd5\xd5;\xe6aB\xbf\x06\xe4\x8a\x00\x8b\x9a\x9f\x99\x99gQ\x81\n\x19\xc0\xb0\xb8\xc9\x12\xd8\\4\x00\x00\xa9\xba\xf3\xb1\xb8|wU\x04\xc2tm\xa1=\x16\xc7^\xa8M\x07\xcf$\xd3*\xde\x04\xd8\x1b\x81\x1b\\5I\xf0\x82\x94\x1c#^l3\x85\xed\x0b\xc4\xe3\x12\x02\xafT\xc5\xeb\x88\x18\xba>;\xdc\xf7\xf9\xf6\x0f\xcf\xaeC\x88\xb8^\xac\x02\x81\x98\xda\x9f0\xc6S\xbb\x89\x80\x82\xa4\xab\x9eC\x85\xb9j\x9d\x04\xb1\x88\xa1\xb2u\xed\x01\xc3\x1e\xd6Z+\r\x04\xde\x935)9E\xe5\xe5E9)\x1a\x19\x84\xff\xe6\x8b7\xda7\x9aJ\x93\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
```

I also tested this way (by modifying the script in the first edit), but with no different results from before:

```
s = open(ic + ".png", "rb")
data = s.read()
ico_img = pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern((255, 255, 255, 255)).create_image(ic_key["dimension"][0], ic_key["dimension"][1])
ico_img.set_data('RGBA', ico_img.width * len('RGBA'), data)
s.close()
```

Comment: If hope you're ok with me changing the title. I think this better matches what you'r asking in the question. If not, feel free to change back to the original title :)

Comment: The new title is fine, in fact, maybe it's better if someone asks my question.

Comment: I'm struggling with reproducing any of the information given in the image data. if I do `open('test.png', 'wb').write(ico['ico_16']['byte'])` and do `identify test.png` (imagemagick), you'll get `identify: improper image header `test.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/4281.` So there's something fishy with the PNG-data. Could you upload your image icon here as a resource?

Comment: Changed the question again :)

Comment: Those bytes strings are completely different from the first ones, why is that? :)

Comment: In this case, the data is a pure PNG. And this is when @snakecharmerb's answer works the best. I missunderstood the question and thought the data you had was pixel-data. But you've got header and everything, and with the latest bytes data you sent, i get: `https://i.imgur.com/1E3KbkZ.png`

Comment: The two new bytes strings are the two new images I used to replace the two icons used at the beginning. In fact, if you use the write method, you get the new images. Still, on pyglet I still get the same problem.

Comment: For the snakecharmerb answer, now also to me now from the image... So it was actually the initial method that gave the error, right?

Comment: I expanded my answer to explain it a bit more. But quire frankly I just think your first images were broken. or in a different format (JPG, GIF or ICO) that you renamed to PNG and tried to load in that format. I also described how you would save **just the image data** without headers etc, so that you can load it as a string without going through a file IO buffer. It's slightly faster but you'll loose the ability to use compression via file formats. Which as a side effect makes it faster as well :) And I think you should mark snakes answer as the correct one, I just contributed more info :)

Comment: Thank you. However, in reality, I think it is due to the fact that before, I obtained the string of bytes from a png image combining BytesIO and PIL (as I also wrote). By changing the method, it now works correctly :)

Comment: Glad it works! :) Best of luck on your project!

Comment: Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @snakecharmerb said is completely true, you could [load it via a BytesIO stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44663628/929999). And it's usually the way most people go. The problem with it is that you need the complete data in order for it to load, otherwise you'll get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    kitten = pyglet.image.load('kitten.png', file=kitten_stream)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyglet\image\__init__.py", line 205, in load
    raise first_exception
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyglet\image\__init__.py", line 195, in load
    image = decoder.decode(file, filename)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyglet\image\codecs\gdiplus.py", line 283, in decode
    bitmap = self._load_bitmap(file, filename)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyglet\image\codecs\gdiplus.py", line 226, in _load_bitmap
    'GDI+ cannot load %r' % (filename or file))
pyglet.image.codecs.ImageDecodeException: GDI+ cannot load 'kitten.png'
```

To get around this, you can create your own valid image structure and in-line replace the data.

And I like quirky solution, so I'll drop this little nugget for anyone who needs to manipulate data/pixels in a way you're planning on doing.

```
ico_img = pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern((255,255,255,255)).create_image(16, 16) # Width, Height
ico_img.set_data('RGB', image_data.width*len('RGB'), ico['ico_16']['byte'])
```

What this does, is basically just crate (pretty quickly) a solid image blob with the right format. Then it in-line replaces the data with whatever you give it. The only important thing here is that your `width` and `height` matches the data-length/format chosen. I assumed the data you've got going is `RGB` and it appears to be working.

Now, I recon this is the fastest way to do it.

But there's a better and almost as fast way of doing it, and it's more readable:

```
ico_img = pyglet.image.ImageData(16, 16, 'RGB', ico['ico_16']['byte'])
```

This accepts any data stream that's valid RGB data (0-255).

Lastly, don't forget to place your image in a sprite object to make it faster and easier to work with:

```
ico_img_sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ico_img)
```

It'll make your life easier in the long run! :)

**Edit**: there are three differences in the first post and the methods to solve this.

Firstly, the original image data appears to be broken, so it's hard/impossible to load.

Secondly, seeing as the new raw data contains meta-data such as headers, creation timestamp etc. It will only be loadable via the `io.BytesIO` method, because it needs to go through [any available image decoder](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/image.html#loading-an-image).

Thirdly, you need to extract the image data (pixel-data) from the image in order to use any methods posted in my answer. Since it will bypass any image encoders and/or compressions. Making it a little bit faster, but at the expense of image data size.

Here is snakes answer working with the new data:

```
raw_image = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x10\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00(-\x0fS\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x01\xc1\x00\x00\x01\xc1\x01E\x85\\9\x00\x00\x00\x19tEXtSoftware\x00www.inkscape.org\x9b\xee<\x1a\x00\x00\x00\xd2PLTE\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00O33gNNm/1l/1t./\x87`cy*-\x86_b\x8f*+\x8efiz,/\x90hl\x94!$\xa1\'(\xa3{|\x8eln\xb4$&\xb9 !\xa1\x88\x8b\x8b"#\xae\x8f\x91\xbc\xa8\xaa\xbe\xb0\xb2\xe4\x19\x1a\xec\x1d\x1d\x90\x8d\x90\x85\x88\x8c\x89\x8b\x8e\x8b\x92\x96\x90\x95\x98\x96\x9e\xa2\x97\x9f\xa3\xa2or\xa4`b\xa9\x19\x1a\xaa\x1b\x1d\xaa\xb5\xba\xaa\xb6\xbb\xab\xb2\xb7\xab\xb3\xb8\xab\xb4\xb8\xab\xba\xc0\xb7\x11\x12\xb9\xc4\xc9\xbe\xc0\xc2\xbf\xbb\xbc\xc4\x14\x15\xd0\xde\xe3\xd6\t\t\xd8\n\n\xd8\xe5\xea\xda\n\n\xda\x0b\x0b\xda\xe6\xeb\xdb\xe7\xec\xdc\xe8\xec\xe0\r\r\xe1\r\r\xe2\xec\xef\xe2\xec\xf0\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\x10\x10\xe8\xf0\xf3\xec\xea\xeb\xf4\x16\x16\xf5\xf8\xfa\xff\x1a\x1a\xff\xff\xff\xeb\x12-N\x00\x00\x00\x1ctRNS\x00\x01-4\x81\x82\x91\x9d\x9e\x9e\xb0\xb2\xb8\xc1\xd0\xd1\xd8\xd9\xe5\xe9\xf1\xf2\xf2\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfd\xfe(\xffw\x99\x00\x00\x00\xb0IDAT\x18\x19=\xc1\x89\x1a\x81@\x14\x06\xd0\x7f\n\x955Id\xdf\xf7\xc24\xd6\x90\xf5\xfd_\xc9\x1d\xfa:\x07\x92\x92\xc9\x96J\xd9\x8c\x82?\x96\xb6\xde?V\x9a\x81\xb0|\xe3\x19\x85\xfb}\x18=\x1by\x06 \xe5\x9ey\xec\xec\xa6\x00\xa5\x12\xf0DPQ\xa0\xef\xb8\xb4\xd9pi\xa7\xa3\xc8\xa5\xc1l6\xe4R\x11\xd5\x15\x19\xcf\xbb\x9d\xf5hE\xaahzd\xbah\xb7\xfc\x89G\x9a\xb0\x85\xd4\xf7\xfd\x9e\x90l\x14\x8e\x82l\x97\xcb\xad \xc7\x02\xd4\xfaA$\x0eu\x15\xd0n\x17\x11\xbb\xdc4\x00\xac\xfcx\xdd\xaf\xa7\xd3\xf5\xfez\x94\x19\x083j\x9f\x9f\x9a\xc1\xf0\xa7\xe6L\xc71s*\xc8\x17B\xf5#3;\xd8r\xdc\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
image_buffer = io.BytesIO(raw_image)
image = pyglet.image.load('temp.png', file=image_buffer)
image_sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet_image)
```

If you want to store the pixel data alone, you could extract it like this:

```
print(image.image_data.get_data('RGBA', 16*4))
```

Where `'RGBA'` is the format you want on the data, and `16*4` is the number of pixels per row times the number of colors per pixel (RBGA is 4).

That will give you the option to do:

```
raw_data = b'\x00\xae\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@b\x00\x00q\xa5\x05\x009XI\x00-I\xa8\x00\'A\xe4\x00%?\xfb\x00%?\xfb\x00\'A\xe4\x00-I\xa8\x009XI\x00q\xa5\x05\x00Be\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xae\xff\x00\x00\x9e\xe9\x00\x00\r\x1c\x00\x00Hm\x18\x00.I\x92\x00#<\xef\x00"<\xff\x00%B\xff\x00(F\xff\x00(F\xff\x00%B\xff\x00"<\xff\x00#<\xef\x00.I\x92\x00Jo\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9f\xea\x00\x00\xcf\xff\x06\x00a\x93 \x00-I\xb2\x00";\xff\x00)G\xff\x002T\xff\x007[\xff\x00;a\xff\x00;c\xff\x009_\xff\x003V\xff\x00)H\xff\x00"<\xff\x00.L\xb3\x00i\xa0#\x00\xcb\xff\x07\x04\xb7\xff\x1e\x06U\x81\xa0\x00)H\xff\x000U\xff\x00<d\xff\x00Cm\xff\x00Hu\xff\x00O\x82\xff\x06]\x94\xff\x04V\x8b\xff\x00Eq\xff\x00<d\xff\x006_\xff\x013Y\xff\x05V\x86\xa2\x02\xb5\xff!\x02v\xb4f2\x8d\xbf\xf3\x10[\x95\xff\x0b[\x97\xff\x04\\\x9a\xff\x02^\x9e\xff\x0cn\xaf\xff\tu\xc6\xffA\xad\xee\xff5\x9f\xdc\xff\x01Z\x92\xff\x00M\x82\xff!u\xb0\xff?\x9b\xd3\xff(\x88\xbf\xf3\x01u\xb5g\x00@l\xb5+{\xab\xff4\xa0\xea\xff:\xaa\xf6\xff4\xa5\xf0\xff,\xa0\xee\xff;\xb0\xfa\xff4\xaf\xfd\xff8\xb3\xff\xff3\xa9\xf4\xff\x05i\xaf\xff\x00d\xad\xffL\xb0\xec\xff[\xc2\xff\xff$w\xad\xff\x00Am\xb5\x004X\xe7*}\xb1\xffD\xb8\xff\xff\x11\x96\xff\xff:\xb4\xff\xff;\xb7\xff\xff\x0f\x99\xff\xffE\xbf\xff\xff8\xb8\xff\xff1\xac\xf9\xff\x03q\xca\xff\x19\x89\xda\xff9\xb4\xfe\xffE\xbb\xff\xff$y\xb0\xff\x003W\xe7\x001R\xfc+\x80\xb6\xffD\xb9\xff\xff\x10\x97\xff\xff9\xb4\xff\xff;\xb7\xff\xff\x0e\x99\xff\xffE\xbe\xff\xff8\xba\xff\xff1\xaf\xfe\xff\x07\x80\xea\xff1\xa5\xf5\xff\x1d\x9e\xff\xffF\xbb\xff\xff$|\xb3\xff\x001Q\xfc\x001R\xfc+\x80\xb6\xffD\xb8\xff\xff\x10\x93\xff\xff:\xb2\xff\xff;\xb5\xff\xff\x0e\x95\xff\xffE\xbe\xff\xff8\xbc\xff\xff0\xb2\xff\xff\x1f\x9d\xfd\xff&\x9b\xf2\xff\x11\x8b\xf6\xffG\xba\xff\xff${\xb2\xff\x001Q\xfc\x004W\xe7*}\xb2\xffD\xb7\xff\xff\x0f\x88\xf5\xff8\xa8\xf4\xff?\xaf\xf6\xff\x0c\x89\xf7\xffE\xbc\xff\xff8\xbd\xff\xff4\xb9\xff\xff8\xb0\xf9\xff\tx\xcf\xff\x12\x80\xdc\xffG\xb7\xfe\xff$x\xae\xff\x003V\xe7\x00>h\xb3+z\xab\xffE\xb5\xf7\xff\x0fv\xc8\xff\x07g\xaa\xff\tl\xad\xff\nw\xcd\xffG\xbb\xfd\xff7\xb9\xff\xff\\\xc7\xff\xff3\x9b\xdc\xff\x00\\\xa4\xff\x13v\xbd\xffH\xb6\xf6\xff%u\xa6\xff\x00=f\xb2\x00X\x8f^"o\x9c\xf2F\xa5\xd8\xff\tY\x92\xff\x00Iw\xff\x00N|\xff\x04b\x9e\xffB\xab\xe6\xff+\xa0\xee\xff=\xa4\xe6\xff\x0ej\xa6\xff\x00L\x7f\xff\x0b[\x93\xffI\xa7\xd9\xff\x1ek\x97\xf2\x00W\x8c]\x00\xa1\xf0\x17\x02Gq\x9d\x056Y\xff\x002X\xff\x00:_\xff\x00Ah\xff\x00Jw\xff\x04Z\x90\xff\x02Z\x97\xff\x00U\x8e\xff\x00Gt\xff\x00<c\xff\x003Y\xff\x057Z\xff\x02Gp\x9d\x00\xa1\xf0\x16\x00\xfa\xff\x03\x00b\x95\x1f\x00-I\xb3\x00"<\xff\x00)G\xff\x002T\xff\x008]\xff\x00;b\xff\x00<d\xff\x009_\xff\x003V\xff\x00)H\xff\x00"<\xff\x00-I\xb3\x00b\x95\x1f\x00\xff\xff\x03\x00\x8b\xce\x00\x00\x15\'\x00\x00In\x18\x00.I\x92\x00#<\xef\x00"<\xff\x00%B\xff\x00(F\xff\x00(F\xff\x00%B\xff\x00"<\xff\x00#<\xef\x00.I\x92\x00In\x18\x00\x16(\x00\x00\x8a\xcc\x00\x00\xaf\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Ac\x00\x00q\xa6\x05\x009XI\x00-I\xa8\x00\'A\xe4\x00%?\xfb\x00%?\xfb\x00\'A\xe4\x00-I\xa8\x009XI\x00q\xa6\x05\x00Ad\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xaf\xff\x00'
image_sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.ImageData(16, 16, 'RGBA', raw_data), x=10, y=10)
```

And in both cases, you'll get a result that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I modified my question, so as to enter the results obtained.

Comment: @BlackFenix06 Most likely just because your image-data has an alpha channel as well. I can correct my code in the morning. But what you need is basically to change `RGB` to `RGBA` in the format descriptor. `ico_img = pyglet.image.ImageData(16, 16, 'RGBA', ico['ico_16']['byte'])` for instance. I'll double check in the morning tho.

Comment: I have tested what you have suggested, but I have no change from the added problem. I tested if it was the byte string that had been badly copied, but it is working. So the problem I have is that I'm doing something wrong that I do not understand, or it's Pyglet who can not do the job ...

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/image.html#loading-an-image), you like load an image from a *file-like object* (like a BytesIO) by specifying the `file` keyword parameter:

```
kitten_stream = io.BytesIO(some_bytes)
kitten = pyglet.image.load('kitten.png', file=kitten_stream)
```

(You may need to rewind the file pointer to the beginning of the file by calling `kitten_stream.seek(0)` before loading).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I modified my question, so as to enter the results obtained.